# the conductor of Hilbert class field of imaginary quadratic field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am trying to learn how to generate hilbert class field of an imaginary quadratic field $K$ in the book Silverman`s Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic curves. I don`t understand some fact in the proof. Let $$(.,L/K): I^\mathfrak{m} \longrightarrow \textrm{Gal}(L/K)$$ be the Artin map for the abelian extension $L/K$ with the conductor $\mathfrak{m}$. We want to prove $L$ is the maximal unramified abelian extension (Hilbert class field) of $K$. At some point in the proof, I reached the following fact: $$((\alpha),L/K)=1 \textrm{ for all } (\alpha)\in I^\mathfrak{m}.$$ Now, somehow I need to see that $\mathfrak{m}$ has to be $(1)$. Because then I will conclude that $L/K$ is unramified. However, to show that $(1)$ is the conductor of the extension $L/K$, first I need to show that $(1)$ is divisible by all ramified primes of $K$, so I need to determine all ramified primes isn`t it? But the book without any explanation just says, the above fact implies that the conductor of $L/K$ is trivial, by the definition of conductor. Maybe I have problem at the definition of conductor. If anyone enlighten me, I would be glad.

Definition of conductor: Let $L/K$ be a finite abelian extension of number fields. Artin reciprocity guarantees the existence of an integral ideal $\mathfrak{c}$ of $K$, divisible by all the primes of $K$ that ramify in $L$, such that $((\alpha,L/K))=1$ for all $\alpha\in K$* satisfying $\alpha\equiv 1$ (mod $\mathfrak{c})$. The largest integral ideal of $K$ among such ideals is called the conductor of $L/K$.

Comment: You're right: the conductor for the Hilbert class field is "1": that is, that ideal class and corresponding extension is "everywhere unramified". Since the case of $\mathbb Q$ cannot illustrate this, it might be useful to do "the next" example of the Hilbert class field of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-5}$ and similar "small" ones. "Unramified" is often awkward to see/describe as the null case of "ramification"...

Comment: I want to show $L/K$ is unramified everywhere. To conclude this, I need to show that the its conductor is (1). This is the exact part I have problem.

Comment: and what is your definition of the Hilbert class field ?

Comment: I define hilbert class field as maximal unramified abelian extension.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If L has conductor m, it cannot be the Hilbert class field unless $m = (1)$.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I try to see $L$ is unramified. To do this it suffices to show the conductor of $L/K$ is (1).  If  $\mathcal{O}_K=(1)$ is divisible by all primes that ramifies in $L$ such that $((\alpha),L.K)=1$ for all $\alpha\in K^*$ with $\alpha\equiv 1\  mod\ \mathfrak{c}$ then it must be the largest ideal among such ideals

Comment: For proving that L is the Hilbert class field of K if you first have to say what L is. And once you know that the ideal group contains all principal ideals coprime to m then you're done.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Let $K/\Bbb{Q}$ be a quadratic imaginary field extension. There exists a homomorphism $$F: Gal(\overline{K}/K)\rightarrow Cl(\mathcal{O}_K)$$ uniquely characterized by the condition $E^\sigma=F(\sigma)*E$ for all $\sigma\in Gal(\overline{K}/K)$ and all $E\in Ell(\mathcal{O}_K).$ L is the fixed field of $ker(F)$. I showed L=k(j(E)) for some CM elliptic curve E by $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: Ok, then as I already said: all principal prime ideals coprime to m split completely in L (by your second displayed equation), hence L is contained in the Hilbert class field and thus has conductor $1$.